# К чему подключается функция connect()?

Tags: c, tcp-ip, unix

Начал читать книгу Стивенса Unix. Разработка сетевых приложений.
Написал свои банальные сервер и клиент. Сервер создает сокет, и ждет пока к нему подключится клиент. Клиент после подключения пишет сообщение, а сервер его на экран выводит.

Но суть вот в чем: если не поднимать сервер, то клиент все равно подключается куда то и отсылает сообщение

сервер:
http://pastebin.com/3WRWJaMT

клиент:
http://pastebin.com/dmEcFeyH

Помогите разобраться, почему так происходит?

Comment: На клиенте не нужен вызов `bind`, Вы этим вызовом создаете сервер, а вызовом `connect` создаете клиента. Причем, обы вызова делаете для одного и того же сокета. Это вообще работать не должно.

Comment: bind можно (а иногда и нужно!) применять на клиенте. Сервер из сокета делает вызов accept.


Код работает странно, потому что connect в случае ошибки возвращает -1, а Вы проверяете на неравенство нулю. Ноль теоретически может быть возвращен и это будет валидный ответ.

Comment: mega, помогло

KoVadim, по-моему, Вы что-то напутали, я ведь как раз и проверяю на ноль)
то есть, если ноль, то посылать сообщение

Comment: Ну да, `bind` на клиенте иногда нужен, например, когда может быть конфликт между двумя сетевыми интерфейсами, а нужно его разрешить для конкретного. Но если не понимаешь архитектуру сети, `bind` может замкнуть клиента в недосягаемом до сервера сегменте сети.  
 --  
Так что, для основной публики повторю: `bind` на клиенте не нужен.

Comment: а как же все таки функция connect подключалась к чему то, если accept() нигде не вызывался.

Comment: >а как же все таки функция connect подключалась к чему то, если accept() нигде не вызывался

к самому себе, но это бред, это работать не должно )

Comment: а у вас подключается? у меня, к слову, и на виртуалке подключается и отсылает

Comment: я проверить не могу, на Wind'ах на данный момент  
 --  
>подключается и отсылает

добавьте в потоке `listen`,`accept` на этом же сокете, получите клиент-сервер-`гермафродит`, пардон, или сам-себе `loopback` ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@knoxx](/users/6222/knoxx), действительно это происходит (connection established) поскольку Вы делаете `bind()` для клиентского сокета и `connect()` **на тот же адрес!!!**.

Попробуйте разнести клиент и сервер по разным машинам и эффект пропадет. Точнее, bind у клиента вернет ошибку (*bind: Cannot assign requested address*), но на последующий `connect()` она не повлияет.

Если указанный порт кто-то там слушает, то соединитесь, если нет, то получите ответ "Connection refused" (или "Connection timed out").